# Class library and static variables in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, static-variables

I have class library which should encapsulates orm logic. To avoid some db calls, it should contain some kind of cache or static variables (I want to avoid them). It's used in asp.net and wcf applications. Since it's class library, I don't want to access Cache or other asp.net related stuff. I also want to avoid static vars because of the application scope nature of them.

How should I implement that? What do you do to achieve this?

EDIT:

To simplify: imagine class library encapsulating DAL. It talks to database. There are some costly queries inside. Some of them should be fetched once per user and stored somewhere and some of them could be used per Application (also stored to avoid future calls to DB). The thing is that normally I would use Cache, but since it's DAL class library, I want to include this functionality inside it (not in asp.net). Hope it's more clear now ;)

Comment: Mate, I don't understand what you are trying to say. Can u try and use some pseduo code or display some workflow of an example scenario. I just don't get what you're asking :(

Answer (score 2):

You should use caching:

- Microsoft Appr Fabrik http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx (former http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/velocity)
- GlynnTucker.Cache http://gtcache.sourceforge.net/
- Shared Cache http://www.sharedcache.com/cms/

Use Patterns, Interfaces etc:

- http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx

Your class library should be loosely coupled. (Easy to exchange and no cross references)

Example (how I'm doing it simplified):

```
namespace MyDbContext
{
    var cache;
    var db;

    public MyDbContext()
    {
        // Cache init
        cache = ....;

        // DB init (can be factory or singleton)
        db = DataBase.Instance();
    }

    public class Car
    {
        // Db tuple id
        public CarId { get; set; }

        public Car(int id)
        {
             CarId = id;
        }

        public Car GetFromDb()
        {
            // your db code will be here
            Car myCar = ....;

            // cache your object
            cache.Put("Car" + CarId.ToString(), myCar);
            return myCar;
        }

        public Car Get()
        {
            // try to get it from cache or load from db
            Car mycar = cache.Get("Car" + CarId.ToString()) as Car ?? GetFromDb();
        }

        public ClearCache()
        {
            cache.Put("Car" + CarId.ToString(), null);
            // maybe cache.Remove("Car" + CarId.ToString())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Andreas Rehm, The real name for Velocity is now `AppFabric Cache`.  I've been doing some research on it lately and it looks very promising.  Download it here, http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=467e5aa5-c25b-4c80-a6d2-9f8fb0f337d2

Comment: Yes - its now AppFabric - you can find more information here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx

Comment: Sorry, but I asked about alternative to statics that can be used INSIDE of class library. I don't want to use Asp.net goodies.

Comment: Andreas, I have. Why do you keep repeating it? Can you give me concrete example of what can be used from Patterns that will help me solve this problem?

Comment: It depends - but I would use a factory pattern.

Comment: Factory? What that has in common with statics in class library (or caching) ?